# Angular2 will not post HTTP

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am creating a registration component, and for some reason when I make the API call to the registration service, absolutely nothing happens. I am using a data context class to make the call to the Angular Http service.

This is in the registration service:

```
return this._webApiDataContext.post(registrationUrl, registration)
        .map(response => { return response.json() });
```

This is in the data context class:

```
post(url: string, data: any) {

    let headers = this._getHeaders();

    // If the data is an object, we need to stringify it first.
    if (typeof data == 'object') {
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    return this._httpClient.post(url, data, { headers });

}
```

Everything works fine until it gets to this._httpClient.post(), and then nothing at all happens.  I've use Fiddler to check network traffic, and it is not making the http call.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Also, I am using this exact same data context method for the login, and that works perfectly. So I know the data context class is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observables are lazy and don't to anything without `subscribe()` or `toPromise()`:

```
 post(someUrl, someData).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Doh! I'm an idiot.  I didn't trace my working login code back up far enough to see that was what was different.  Thanks!